# Skipping a step on CircleCI Orb build, version 2.1

Tags: java, github, gradle, continuous-integration, circleci-orb

I am using CircleCI CI/CD service. I have a basic build config for Java project with Gradle and Java 1.8. It works fine.
Here is the source of my *.circleci/config.yml* file

```
executors:
  java1_8:
    docker:
      - image: 'cimg/openjdk:8.0'
orbs:
  gradle: circleci/gradle@2.2.0
version: 2.1
workflows:
  checkout-build-test:
    jobs:
      - gradle/test:
          executor: java1_8
```

After completing the build CircleCI uploads artifacts and this is taking a lot of time.
I am looking for a way to **skip** the "Uploading Artifacts" **step**.

I can change to CircleCI version 2.0 if needed, but it would be nice to configure 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to skip the step.
It turned out to be not very hard.

First, in **gradle** we can skip steps if we add a  `-x "step-to-skip"` command-line parameters.

Second, CircleCi Gradle Orb can be configured with **custom 'test' commands**.
Here is the documentation: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/gradle#jobs-test

I have combined these two features to get a working configuration.

So, if I need to **skip** 'javaDoc' step, I would modify my **CircleCi** *config.yml* file in the following manner:

```yaml
executors:
  java1_8:
    docker:
      - image: 'cimg/openjdk:8.0'
orbs:
  gradle: circleci/gradle@2.2.0
version: 2.1
workflows:
  checkout-build-test:
    jobs:
      - gradle/test:
          test_command: test -x javaDoc
          executor: java1_8
```